# Create-react-app registerServiceWorker giving undefined at getRegistration() promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

First, it is working on PC but doesn't on a mobile device, that is my main problem.

I created a PWA using create-react-app and I'm trying to implement push notifications but seems like I get undefined at the 'reg' argument of my promise. Someone knows how to make this works? I already try to eject create-react-app but gives the same problem.

I added this code to **registerServiceWorker.js**:

```
export function displayNotification() {
  if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
    console.log('this is showing at console when i click the button')
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(reg) {
      reg.showNotification('Hello world!');
    });
  }
}
```

**Error:**

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property
>   'showNotification' of undefined

This issue talks about this problem but I already tried those solutions and the error is the same.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2253#issuecomment-312359460

Those below are an old version that only works at browser PC, and at PWA gives a blank page when clicking the button.

My PWA: https://danilosilvadev.github.io/pwa-test/

My code: https://github.com/danilosilvadev/pwa-test/tree/master

If help me with this old version that uses an npm package called *"react-web-notification": "^0.3.1"* or with the code that I provided in this question that is my attempt to do manually anyway I'd be grateful.

Comment: What is the exact version of your mobile device's browser and OS?

Comment: The latest.Did it work on your phone?

Comment: I am seeing this issue on my Android phone running Chrome Canary. The API appears to be behaving different on Android. Try using `self.registration` instead of the `navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()` promise.

Comment: I did use and got `Unexpected use of 'self'  no-restricted-globals`.

Comment: That sounds like an ESLint error due to it not knowing that this is a web worker file. Ignore the error and try it on your mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my computer: Chrome + Windows and it's working.

[image]

Comment: At PC it is working, but at cellphone android, it is not. Try to test on your mobile device and you will see the error.